# How do get the data stream link for any video of youtube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this question,I googled a lot about this,but nothing turned up,. for a link of the form

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[video_id]

How do i get the link for the data stream?

Answer (score 3):

The following bash script will retrieve youtube streaming url's. I know this is outdated, but maybe this will help someone.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && printf "usage: `basename $0` <youtube_url>\n" && exit 1

ID="$(echo "$1" | grep -o "v=[^\&]*" | sed 's|v=||')"
URL="$(curl -s "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=$ID" | sed -e 's|%253A|:|g' -e 's|%252F|/|g' -e 's|%253F|?|g' -e 's|%253D|=|g' -e 's|%2525|%|g' -e 's|%2526|\&|g' -e 's|\%26|\&|g' -e 's|%3D|=|g' -e 's|type=video/[^/]*&sig|signature|g' | grep -o "http://o-o---preferred[^:]*signature=[^\&]*" | head -1)"

[ -z "$URL" ] && printf "Nothing was found...\n" && exit 2

echo "$URL"
```

Comment: This script is obsolete, needs to be updated (to use https etc)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick lesson in reverse-engineering the YouTube page to extract the stream data.

In the HTML you'll find a **<script> tag** which defines a variable "swfHTML" - it looks like this: "var swfHTML = (isIE) ? "...

The text in the quotes that follows that snippet is the HTML that displays the Flash object. *Note, this text is a set of broken up strings that get concatenated so you'll need to clean it up* (i.e. strip instances of '" + "' and and escaping backslashes in order to get the HTML string.)

Once clean you'll need to find the **<param> tag** with **name="flashvars"**, the value of this tag is an &-delimited URL. Do a split on the & and you'll get your key-value pairs for all the data relating to this video.

The main **key you're looking for** is "**fmt_url_map**" and it's an URL Encoded string of Comma-Separated Values starting with "35|" or "34|" or other. (These are defined in another key, "**fmt_list**" to be files of resolution 854x480 for 35, 640x360 for 34, etc..)

Comment: Make a GET request (using CURL, Fiddler, or something else) for one of the URLs. Make sure to include the appropriate Request Headers (Cookie and Host and possibly others). I grabbed the YouTube cookies from my browser. I've tested this manually using Fiddler and I've been able to download a few videos.

Answer (score 0):

each channel provides rss-data, wich is not updated immediatelly.

Here is a generator for Youtube RSS Files. You should be able to deduce the location of videofiles based on the RSS information. The flv files should be streamable but other formats are also provided.

EDIT: 
 `http://www.referd.info/` is no longer available. It basically was a service where you provided the youtube link and it dereferenced it found all possible downloadsources for that video. I am sure those services are still out there... this one isnt anymore.

Comment: [KeepVid](http://keepvid.com) seems to work, the only problem is it's Java applet.

Answer (score 0):

You Need Open Link Like This
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=OjEG808MfF4
And Find Your Stream Your In Return Data